# vim, switching between files rapidly using vanilla Vim (no plugins)

Tags: vim

I understand that limiting myself to vanilla Vim (not using plugins) limits the power of the editor, but as I switch between different machines frequently, it is often too much trouble to move my environment around everywhere. I want to just stay in vanilla Vim.

Something that holds me back is the ability to quickly switch between files.
I (believe at least) have a good understanding of *buffers*, *windows*, *tabs*, as well as netrw (`Vex`, `Ex`, etc).

But in an editor such as [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/), I can just type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> and instantly I am at the file.

I know that I can drop down to the shell, but I wonder if there are any other "hidden" secrets to rapidly switching between files in Vim based off more than just the filename.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it might persuade you to consider using plugins: http://dudarev.com/blog/keep-vim-settings-and-plugins-in-git-repo/

Comment: I personally sync my settings with Dropbox. It's clumsy but it more or less works without having to think about it. The one plugin I use and know works well for what you want is Command-T (https://github.com/wincent/Command-T). Ctrl-P could be an alternative (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736).

Comment: Have you seen http://www.danielmiessler.com/study/vim/? He has the very smart practive of putting his vimrc + all the plugns he needs into Github ... anmywhere he goes he can clone it and voila, Vim is exactly as he likes. Brilliant

Comment: @bobox, tens of thousands of people do that; there's nothing extraordinary about that.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

The closest equivalent ("closest", not "exact") to ST2's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> is a plugin called, get ready… [CtrlP](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736). There are other similar plugins like [Command-T](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025) or [FuzzyFinder](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984).

I use CtrlP and I love it but I wholeheartedly support your decision to go "plugin-free". It's not the easiest way to go but it will pay off in the long run.

---

**Opening files**

The most basic way to open a file is `:e /path/to/filename`. Thankfully, you get tab-completion and wildcards: the classic `*` and a special one, `**`, which stands for "any subdirectory".

Combining all of that, you can do:

```
:e **/*foo<Tab>
```

to choose from all the files containing `foo` in their name under the working directory or:

```
:e **/*foo/*bar<Tab>
```

to choose from all the files containing `bar` in their name under any subdirectory containing `foo` in its name, anywhere under the working directory.

Of course, that works for `:tabe[dit]`, `:sp[lit]` and `:vs[plit]`, too.

Those commands are limited to one file, though. Use `:next` to open multiple files:

```
:next **/*.js
```

and take a look at `:help arglist`.

---

**Jumping between buffers**

`:b[uffer]` is the basic buffer-switching command:

```
:b4         " switch to buffer number 4
:bn         " switch to next buffer in the buffer list
:bp         " switch to previous buffer in the buffer list
:bf         " switch to first buffer in the buffer list
:bl         " switch to last buffer in the buffer list
:b foo<Tab> " switch by buffer name with tab-completion
:b#         " switch to the alternate file
```

Note that many of these commands and their relatives accept a count.

The `:ls` command shows you a list of loaded buffers. It is a bit "special", though: buffers are assigned a number when they are created so you can have a list that looks like `1 2 5` if you delete buffers. This is a bit awkward, yes, and that makes switching to a buffer by its number a bit too troublesome. Prefer switching by partial name, `:b foo<Tab>` or cycling, `:bn :bp`.

Anyway, here is a cool mapping that lists all loaded buffers and populates the prompt for you, waiting for you to type the number of a buffer and press `<enter>`:

```
nnoremap gb :ls<CR>:b<Space>
```

With this mapping, switching to another buffer is as simple as:

```
gb
(quickly scanning the list)
3<CR>
```

or:

```
gb
(quickly scanning the list)
foo<tab><CR>
```

The idea comes from this image [taken from Bairui's collection of Vim infographics](http://of-vim-and-vigor.blogspot.ro/p/vim-vigor-comic.html):

[image: Flying vs cycling]

Vim also has `<C-^>` (or `<C-6>` on some keyboards)—the normal mode equivalent of `:b#`—to jump between the current buffer and the previous one. Use it if you often alternate between two buffers.

Read all about buffers in `:help buffers`.

---

**Go to declaration**

Within a file, you can use `gd` or `gD`.

Within a project, Vim's "tags" feature is your friend but you'll need an external code indexer like ctags or cscope. The most basic commands are `:tag foo` and `<C-]>` with the cursor on a method name. Both tools are well integrated into Vim: see `:help tags`, `:help ctags` and `:help cscope`.

For what it's worth, I use tag navigation extensively to move within a project (using CtrlP's `:CtrlPTag` and `:CtrlPBufTag` commands, mostly, but the buit-in ones too) and my favorite "generic" buffer switching method is by name.

---

**Deploying your config**

A lot of Vim users put their config under version control which makes it *very* quick and easy to install your own config on a new machine. Think about it.

---

***EDIT***

A few months ago, I had to work on a remote machine with an outdated Vim. I could have installed a proper Vim and cloned my own beloved config but I decided to travel light, this time, in order to "sharpen the saw". I quickly built a minimalist `.vimrc` and revisited a couple of half forgotten native features. After that gig, I decided CtrlP wasn't that necessary and got rid of it: native features and custom mappings are not as sexy but they get the job done without much dependencies.

---

**Juggling with files**

```
set path=.,**
nnoremap <leader>f :find *
nnoremap <leader>s :sfind *
nnoremap <leader>v :vert sfind *
nnoremap <leader>t :tabfind *
```

`:find` is a truly great command as soon as you `set path` correctly. With my settings, `,ffoo<Tab>` will find all the files containing `foo` under the current directory, recursively. It's quick, intuitive and lightweight. Of course, I benefit from the same completion and wildcards as with `:edit` and friends.

To make the process even quicker, the following mappings allow me to skip entire parts of the project and find files recursively under the directory of the current file:

```
nnoremap <leader>F :find <C-R>=expand('%:h').'/*'<CR>
nnoremap <leader>S :sfind <C-R>=expand('%:h').'/*'<CR>
nnoremap <leader>V :vert sfind <C-R>=expand('%:h').'/*'<CR>
nnoremap <leader>T :tabfind <C-R>=expand('%:h').'/*'<CR>
```

**WARNING! The `path` option is *extremely* powerful. The value above—`.,**`—works *for me*, *as a default fallback value*. In the real world, the exact value of the option will differ from project/language/framework/workflow to project/language/framework/workflow, so the *proper* value depends entirely on *your* needs. Don't blindly copy that line and expect it to solve all your problems.**

---

**Juggling with buffers**

```
set wildcharm=<C-z>
nnoremap <leader>b :buffer <C-z><S-Tab>
nnoremap <leader>B :sbuffer <C-z><S-Tab>
```

The mappings above list the available buffers in the "wildmenu" with an empty prompt, allowing me to either navigate the menu with `<Tab>` or type a few letters and `<Tab>` again to narrow down the list. Like with the file mappings above, the process is quick and almost friction-less.

```
nnoremap <PageUp>   :bprevious<CR>
nnoremap <PageDown> :bnext<CR>
```

Those mappings speak for themselves.

---

**Juggling with tags**

```
nnoremap <leader>j :tjump /
```

This mapping uses regex search instead of whole word search so I can do `,jba<Tab>` to find tag `foobarbaz()`.

Yes, fuzzy matching is addictive but you can be just as productive without it. And for a fraction of the cost.

---

***MORE EDIT***

A couple of additional tips/tricks…

---

**Wildmenu options**

The "wildmenu", enabled with `set wildmenu`, makes file/buffer navigation easier. Its behavior is governed by a bunch of options that are worth investigating:

`wildmode` tells Vim how you want the "wildmenu" to behave:

```
set wildmode=list:full
```

`wildignore` filters out all the cruft:

```
set wildignore=*.swp,*.bak
set wildignore+=*.pyc,*.class,*.sln,*.Master,*.csproj,*.csproj.user,*.cache,*.dll,*.pdb,*.min.*
set wildignore+=*/.git/**/*,*/.hg/**/*,*/.svn/**/*
set wildignore+=tags
set wildignore+=*.tar.*
```

`wildignorecase` allows you to search for `foo` and find `Foo`:

```
set wildignorecase
```

---

**File marks**

```
augroup VIMRC
  autocmd!

  autocmd BufLeave *.css  normal! mC
  autocmd BufLeave *.html normal! mH
  autocmd BufLeave *.js   normal! mJ
  autocmd BufLeave *.php  normal! mP
augroup END
```

I recently found this gem in someone else's `~/.vimrc`. It creates a file mark at the exact position of the cursor whenever you leave a buffer so that, wherever you are, `'J` jumps to the latest JavaScript buffer you edited. Awesome.

Comment: +1. I had no idea about the "any subdirectory" in combination with `:e` but I'll be using it **a lot** from now on. I marvel at the work that got into Ctrl-P and can learn a lot from it but it didn't work for me. I found it to be a bit slugish and as such interrupting my train of thought while working *(could be my system, my settings, myself but I didn't investigate)*

Comment: I'd love to upvote again for the `gb` map. Another one I'll use a lot. All buffer plugins I have tried *(CtrlP, bufExplorer, ...)* are not nearly as fast as this *(granted, they offer more functionality but not enough for me to keep using them)*.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, [this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-d1GaUBk-Y10/TyFhskmCYRI/AAAAAAAAARQ/CIEx1V7FLqg/s1600/vim-and-vigor-004-flying_is_faster_than_cycling.png) is where I got it from and [this](http://of-vim-and-vigor.blogspot.fr/p/vim-vigor-comic.html) is where the silly picture comes from. Thanks Bairui!

Comment: Sometimes it is also handy to go sequentially through a list of files (e.g., if you did something like `vim *.php` to open several files at once). Then you can use `:n[ext]` (as well as `:prev[ious]`, `:fir[st]`, and `:la[st]`).

Comment: @chris, you should develop that comment into a full answer.

Comment: @romainl: I did "turn" it into an answer... there was not much "development" ;)... if something more comes to my mind, I'll add it later. And thanks for the hint.

Comment: Related, but probably counterproductive to the awesome ** tip, is `set autochdir`, which keeps updating your working directory to be the current file's.

Comment: :e **/foo is the awesome. Im 100% with @Jonathan.Brink - file navigation in vim sucks.

Comment: I think `wildmenu` and `wildmode` are more orthogonal than your description. You can have either without the other, however, `wildmode` can disable `wildmenu` if `full` is not used. See `:help wildmenu`.

Comment: @BradyTrainor, they are not orthogonal at all but you are right that a poor choice of values can render the whole thing useless.

Comment: Perhaps not orthogonal, but `set nowildmenu` and `set wildmode=list:full` is a reasonable setting, and pulls the emphasis away from the word wildmenu for me. My section in .vimrc for these is simply titled "wilds". I'm splitting hairs really. Then again, `wildmenu` is a reasonable title anyhow, if viewed as, the topic wildmenu includes the settings `wildmenu`, `wildmode`, ...

Comment: @BradyTrainor, that's why I presented the wildmenu like that. This answer is by no means an exhaustive tutorial so I did some generalization. Going through all the possible variations of `wildmenu` and `wildoption` would be too much for the reader.

Comment: Oops... I did not mean to recommend that last setting (I am indeed using `wildmenu` and `list:full`), only thinking out loud about the existence of configurations which make the two seem more orthogonal. Many pardons! And your presentation is awesome! I just couldn't help but to ponder, since I was just getting more familiar with that particular group.

Comment: I would add `b#` to the "Jumping between buffers" list. It switches to the previously active buffer.

Comment: @bnjmn, you are right, that feature is already covered in my answer with `<C-^>`, the normal mode equivalent of `:b#`, which IMO is more intuitive. But I'll add `:b#` anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Late to the party, but why do we need space in `nnoremap gb :ls<CR>:b<Space>`?

Comment: @Džuris, welcome to the party. *We* don't need that `<Space>` but *I* want it because I find the command-line easier to parse that way.

Answer (score 5):

The answer depends a lot on your preferences and circumstances. Some examples:

- If it's mostly two files (e.g. a C header and implementation file), `<C-^>` is very handy. In general, the *alternate file* is an important concept.
- If you use a large editor window, window `:split`s turn the problem of locating a buffer from locating the window (once you've got all buffers opened). You can use `[N]<C-w><C-w>` to quickly switch to it.
- If you can memorize (a few) buffer numbers, the `:[N]b[uffer]` and `:[N]sb[uffer]` commands are quite handy; `:ls` tells you the numbers.

Plugins (or at least custom mappings) can improve things a lot, and there's a whole variety on this topic on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/). There are various mechanisms to distribute your config (Pathogen + GitHub, Dropbox, ...), or you could remotely edit server files through the *netrw* plugin that ships with Vim.

Comment: Would probably worth mentioning ctags, cscope, gtags, id, and friends. I find using uppercase marks to be very helpful. Use `mA` to store mark `A` and ````A``` to return. I find *netrw* much more useful after I learned about `:Rex` which returns to explorer. `:b`, `:e`, and many others can take wildcards like `*` and `**`. The `:b` command can take a partial filename. Combine that with `<c-d>` or the wildmenu you can get pretty far. As for plugins you can use something domain specific like rail.vim which provides rails specific navigation commands or something more general like CtrlP.

Comment: @PeterRincker: +1 for mentioning about marks. I suggest constructing an answer with marks.

Comment: What does <C-^> and [N]<C-w><C-w> mean?

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes it is also handy to go sequentially through a list of files (e.g., if you did something like `vim *.php` to open several files at once). Then you can use `:n[ext]` (as well as `:prev[ious]`, `:fir[st]`, and `:la[st]`) for navigation (in addition to what was suggested in the other answers).

Answer (score 4):

You can do wildcard tab completion on the command line without any plugins. e.g.

```
:e src/**/foo*<tab>
```

will let you cycle through all the files starting with 'foo' in the directory tree under ./src and select the one you want to edit.

If you have already edited the file and it is still in a buffer then you can switch to it with:

```
:b foo<tab>
```

which will cycle through all the buffers with 'foo' in the path.
You may need to set the wildmode and wildmenu options to get the behaviour you want.  I have

```
wildmode=longest:full
wildmenu
```

in my .vimrc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a filename and want to jump to that file, [`gf`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_under_cursor) will do it for you. I also like using [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), which isn't a plugin; you just build the tags and can easily jump around your codebase.

Answer (score 1):

If you want switch between files in vim editor, please see below answer

First press `Esc` key to exit from edit mode.

Then type `:e` to check current file path.

if you want to go another file then  type `:e /path-of-file.txt/` using this you are able to switch.

If you want to go previous file simply type `:e#` which switch to previous file path.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Vim.

The last thing I want is to depend on plugins for a task as mundane as file switching.

I added the following lines to `.vimrc`

```
set path+=**
set wildmenu
```

And BAM! I can now `:find any/filename/in/any/folder/` as long as vim is in the root directory of the project. **Tab completion works. Wildcards work!**

Once files are opened already, and there are a ton of buffers in the background (you could use `:ls` to see all buffers), running `:b any/file <TAB>` will fuzzy search for all buffers and jumps to the required file. In case it is not unique there will be a *wildmenu* of tabs (hence the 2nd line in .vimrc) which can be selected using tab.

My answer is coming from this awesome video
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XA2WjJbmmoM&feature=youtu.be&t=489
There are more tricks in and I recommend watching it.