# How to open files with pattern recursively in vim

Tags: linux, vim

Guys how do i open multiple files in vim with a single command?

These files i want to open has some kind of pattern, example:

```
myfile1dsa
myfile2dsdas
myfile3xzczxcz
```

and also do these opened files create their own tab in my vim window?

**and out of topic question:**

what does "--" means in a linux command? how does it differ from just "-"?

example:

```
grep --color 'data' fileName
```

Comment: GNU (and POSIX) defines option flags with one `-` as one-letter 'short options'. Double minuses indicate long options (that are longer than a single letter). This is not always the case (the X convention uses options such as `-display` often)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can open them from within `vim` using

```
:args myfile*
```

or if you want to open all files matching the pattern in subfolders

```
:args **/myfile*
```

This all assumes your current directory is the folder from wich you want to open files from. Prepend a directory to myfile if it's not.

```
:args /yourfolder/myfile*
:args /yourfolder/**/myfile*
```

**Edit (cudo's to romainl)**

To open all the files found in tabs, you can use

```
:argdo tabe
```

wich essentially goes like this:

- `argdo`: for each file in the argument list
- `tabe` : open a new tabpage and edit the file

Comment: care to explain what the ** means in your second args

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated, it's easy to explain but `:h **` is better.

Comment: it only opens the first occurence of myfile. I am expecting to open several tabs

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated - it's the convention used to traverse all subfolders to find the file matching the pattern.

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated, once the arglist is populated, do `:argdo tabe`.

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated - All your files are available in buffers, not in tabs. Using buffers is the defacto way of working with vim (at least, it is for me). Cudo's to romainl for adding the extra bit on opening them in tabs.

Comment: how to navigate through the buffer. and i entered :argdo tabe 2 times. now i have several duplicate files. help

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated: each file is represented by one buffer but that buffer may be displayed in 0 or more windows in 0 or more tabs. I totally backup Lieven's comment on using buffers instead of tabs. Take the time to read `:h windows`.

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated - You navigate through buffers using `:bn(ext)` or `:bp(revious)`. Personally, I have mapped `:bn<CR>` to `<C-N>` for easy navigating and mapped `<leader>b` to `:ls<CR>:b<Space>` as it's the fastest way I've found to work with a buffer list. That part also came from romainl if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: ... and offcourse it did. You should definitely read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082991/vim-switching-between-files-rapidly/16084326#comment22986046_16084326)

Comment: *"You can open them from within vim"* and likewise from the shell command line: `vim myFile*`, `vim **/myFile*`, etc. with exactly the same result (having buffers numbered from '1' and not '2' if one cares).