# Equivalent of Sublime Text's Goto Anything (i.e. Command + P) in vim

Tags: vim, sublimetext2

As per title, is there an equivalent of Sublime Text's Goto Anything (i.e. Command + P) in vim?  Or some way to quickly navigating to files by typing part of their path in?

Comment: Care to write a plugin for it? That would be great.

Comment: This has already been answered in [vim, switching between files rapidly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16084326).