# Finding files in Rails application using Vim - Whats the command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, editor

I'm brand new to Vim so I'll be SUPER clear about what my question is. Right now I have an application and I'm in the root directory with vim(I'll post a screenshot for clarity). I want to navigate to the `Users_controller.rb` with a vim command, something like `:e users_controller.rb` but I don't know what the actual command is? I feel like the answer to this question should be easy but I can't find it anywhere.

Here is my current position in vim

[image]

As you can see on the left I have my full application but now I want to simply navigate to a particular file(like fuzzyfinder in atom)How can I do this?

Comment: The actual command is `:e app/constrollers/users_controller.rb` or with autocomplete `:e ap<TAB>/con<TAB>/use<TAB>`

Comment: hmm That's so weird then. When ever I type that command it starts a new directory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082991/vim-switching-between-files-rapidly-using-vanilla-vim-no-plugins/16084326#16084326

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This you can do without any plugin, plain vanilla `vim` using `:find` and extending `path`.

```
:set path+=** "Extends path to look into all sub-folders, :help path
```

Now use `:find users_controller.rb` or even `:find users_*.rb` to locate and open the file. Details at `:help :find`

Base on the number of sub folders in your project, `find` may take sometime to search the file.

---

But you will be lot happier with `ctrl-p` plugin, though there are many ways to accomplish that.
Just type ctrl + p and name of file. You need to install the plugins from https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim