# How to make switching buffers easier in Vim?

Tags: vim

I'm coming from emacs where switching switching buffers (and browsing them) is really easy, compared to vim where it's a pain. What can I do to make it faster/easier?

Comment: Read this answer of @romainl: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16084326/5048383

Comment: What exactly is your problem with buffer switching and why in all hell do you think it's hard?